# get List of Running running app's in Mobile

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am developing an android application and I need a functionality like, collect all opened app's info for Android (Version 10,11).

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UsageStatsManager`. To use it you will need to add `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` to manifest and the user will have to grant access from the settings.

> NOTE: Most methods on this API require the permission
> android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS. However, declaring the
> permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device
> still needs to grant permission through the Settings application. See
> Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS. Methods which only return the
> information for the calling package do not require this permission.
> E.g. getAppStandbyBucket() and queryEventsForSelf(long, long).

When you have permission granted, you can call this function:

Kotlin:

```
val usm = getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
val appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time)
```

Java:

```
UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time);
```

`queryUsageStats`

> Gets application usage stats for the given time
> range, aggregated by the specified interval.The returned list will
> contain one or more objects for each package, with usage data that
> covers at least the given time range.Note: The begin and end times of
> the time range may be expanded to the nearest whole interval period.

Interval constants:

- INTERVAL_DAILY
- INTERVAL_WEEKLY
- INTERVAL_MONTHLY
- INTERVAL_YEARLY
- INTERVAL_BEST

If you need more information you can see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager).

Comment: val usm = getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
val appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time)

Comment: i think above code is Kotlin but i am using java is there any way in java

Comment: There is no problem, you can easily convert it to java.
UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager ) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE)
... etc.

Comment: It is giving o/p like empty array. i want out put like  ex:[com.google.chrome , com.google.youtube , ..... e.t.c]

Comment: Make sure you have granted permission.You can get package name from UsageStats class. F.e: appList[0].getPackageName();

Comment: yes .I am giving permission still it is giving same output